# Jenkins-X CD with JAR file and Version Number

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-x

Please I am new to CI/CD generally, I have studied some of the jenkins-x docs, the following is the process we currently use:

1.) I am  provided with a JAR URL file download (compiled by a different team entirely) and a respective version number.

2.) Then use a Dockerfile to build the image with the version number and push to AWS ECR.

3.) k8s deployment manifest file is updated with the new version number and deployed to the kubernetes cluster.

But there is no quickstarts templates for this kind of scenario, what is the best way to implement this with Jenkins-X?

***https://github.com/jenkins-x/draft-packs/tree/master/packs/appserver*** -- This looks somehow close to what I want to achieve but am not entirely sure which parts I should remove from the Jenkins file/other files.

Also we use bitbucket server (was able to integrate this into jenkins-x), how should the trigger be configured.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins-X draft packs are geared towards building and deploying an app from source code. The scenario you describe is deploying a provided app from an already-built jar. You could still use Jenkins-X but you would need to do some pipeline customisation. You could use the draft pack that you point to on doing 'jx import' and that would generate a starting-point for you. Then you could change the dockerfile to replace 'war' with 'jar', remove any Java source code and put the jar there and you would also need to modify the generated Jenkinsfile to take out the Maven-related build steps.